# Figure numbering without caption

Tags: graphics, captions

I would like to add a simple caption "Figure [number]" before an image in my document. If I just use

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{galor3.png}
\end{figure}
```

there is no caption.

If I add

```
\caption{}
```

I get the caption "Figure 1.1:". Of course, this code generates a colon, because it expects some caption after the figure number. I would like to have the images numbered without the colon. Is it possible? Thanks

Comment: Just add `\usepackage{caption}` in the preamble

Comment: `[!h]` is highly likely to take the figure to the end of the document, or make a bad page break, or both. You should almost always include at least `p`

Comment: @Luigi you're welcome. Hope your thesis is coming up well!

Comment: Hi @karlkoeller, I had not realized that you were the same answerer of the question about the frontispiece. If things keep going this way, I'll have to add your name to the acknowledgments! :) The thesis is coming up well.

I apologize for the duplicate. I always look for duplicates, but this time I've missed it.

Thank you too DavidCarlisle.